# react classnames if else

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I changed my file Order.css to Order.module.css. And now I need to transform this condition from

```
const firstNameClass = firstNameInputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control';
...
<div className={firstNameClass}>
...
</div>
```

in something like this

```
   const firstNameClass = firstNameInputHasError ? classes['form-control'] + classes['invalid'] : classes['form-control'];
```

first-line works fine when the name of the file is Order.css. The second line doesn't work.

---

Updated. Thanks to chenc that recommended classnames package

---

My solution

```
import classes from './Order.module.css';
import classNames from "classnames/bind";

let classNameBound = classNames.bind(classes);

const firstNameClass = classNameBound(
    classes["form-control"],
    {invalid: firstNameInputHasError}
);
```

Second solution without classnames package

```
const firstNameClass = `${classes["form-control"]} ${firstNameInputHasError ?  classes.invalid : ''}`;
```

Comment: The second line doesn't work how?

Answer (score 2):

why not use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) ?
This is a good package for judging conditions to use class

Comment: Would look lie this,

className={classNames(classes['form-control'], { classes['invalid']: firstNameInputHasError })}>

Answer (score 1):

**It should be in a function, and you don't need to use a `+`:**

```
const firstNameClass = firstNameInputHasError
  ? classes(["form-control invalid"])
  : classes(["form-control"]);
```

**Or in short:**

```
const firstNameClass = classes(["form-control", {
    'invalid': firstNameInputHasError
  }
]);
```